# How to upgrade gfortran

Tags: ubuntu, installation, g++4.8

I am using ubuntu 12.04, with gcc/g++ 4.8, the gfortran is 4.6, I reinstalled gfortran-4.8 and gfortran-4.8.dev, still not linking.

When I tried to compile a project, it doesn't link to gfortran, how do I upgrade to gfortran 4.8?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.04, GNU Fortran 95 compiler 4.8 (gfortran) can be installed from the terminal using this command:

```
sudo apt install gfortran
```